# Rails: How to include multiple web fonts into rails asset pipeline using bower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bower, font-awesome

I want to include multiple custom web fonts to my rails asset pipeline and the fonts are not loaded.

My folder structure:

[image]

In my `application.rb` file,

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "bower_components", "font-awesome","fonts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "bower_components", "simple-line-icons","fonts")

config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf|woff2)\z/
```

But still the fonts are not loaded into application. Can someone please help me?. I am using `Bower` to install the fonts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I really like this this article [persuading rails to serve all bower assets](https://liggat.org/persuading-rails-to-serve-all-bower-assets/)

Things that are important to know is that you include font times in the assets initializers like this

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
types = %w( *.png *.gif *.jpg *.eot *.woff *.ttf )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += types
```

I hope that this and that article are able to help

Comment: Thanks. But my question was to include multiple fonts like font-awesome and simple-line-icons and couldn't address that.